# What is the name of the style of jacket in this picture?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

[image: a picture of Japanese rock band "Nico Touches the Walls"]

I wanted to know what is the name of this kind of jacket, the blue one with golden buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a [military-style jacket](https://www.google.com/search?q=military%20style%20jacket%20mens&safe=active&client=ms-android-google&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkyL_a6fTSAhUIYyYKHVT3A5kQ_AUICSgC&biw=518&bih=760) (see Google Image search in link for many examples).

Key features are the close fit, brass buttons, epaulets (shoulder things), the stand-up collar, and the single-breasted front with buttons all the way up to the neck.

Of course military uniforms vary tremendously (think of bomber jackets or modern camouflage), but variations on this style have been popular in a surprisingly wide array of militaries for the past century or so. You can see many examples in the [Imperial War Museum's collections](http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/search?query=Uniform%20jacket&items_per_page=10), such as this 1907 imperial Russian artillery jacket:

[image: khaki jacket with red piping and two breast pockets]© IWM (UNI 12425)

This more elaborate version from the Hussars (WWI era): [image: blue military Hussars jacket with gold piping]
© IWM (UNI 5174)

This British Arab Legion patrol jacket from 1952:
[image: Single-breasted jacket of dark blue cloth with a stand collar and two flapped breast pockets]© IWM (UNI 6488)

And this contemporary US Navy dress uniform:

[image: US Navy 041015-N-0000F-001 Vice Adm. Charles L. Munns salutes as he passes through side boys as the new Commander, Naval Submarine Forces](U.S. Navy photo by Photographer's Mate 2nd Class Alisha M. Frederick)